# Grouping Value using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I got the following data on a table, I want to make a macro that will group all the values with `#N/A` right at the bottom. Please assist.

```
       A         B                     C        D           E
1     Line      Item               Quantity Part Number Description
2     Line 1    Fan Motor           0           0          0
3     Line 2    Fan                #N/A      #N/A         #N/A
4     Line 3    Fan guard           0           0          0
5     Line 4    Pump                0           0          0
6     Line 5    Access door         0           0          0
7     Line 6    Nozzle grommet      0           0          0
8     Line 7    Nozzle              0           0          0
9     Line 20   SST tube            0           0          0
10    Line 21   Flanges             2      205024M2P     HDGFLG  
11    Line 22   Part 11             #N/A      #N/A        #N/A
12    Line 23   Part 12             #N/A      #N/A        #N/A
16    Line 29   Terminal box         1     31123800P     TERMINAL BOX
14    Line 25   Check Valve         #N/A      #N/A        #N/A
15    Line 26   Buttefly Valve      #N/A      #N/A        #N/A
17    Line 30   Solenoid valve       1     31601700P     SOLENOID VALVE 1 PER8
18    Line 31   Coil                 1     31602000P     COIL FOR SOL. VALVE
```

I used the code below initially to delete rows with value `#N/A`

```
Sub GroupRows()
    Dim rownum As Long

    For rownum = 1 To 1000
        If Cells(rownum, 3).Text = "#N/A" Then
            Rows(rownum).Delete

    Next rownum
    Cells(rownum, 3).Activate
End Sub
```

but a

> "Compile error: Next without For"

error message pops up, thing is I am still new to VBA and there's some things I do not quite understand as of yet, so I do not know whether I am coding right or not.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. First of all this is not a free code writing service so you will need to show (the code) what you already have done (Read [ask]). Secondly "*group all the values with `#N/A` right at the bottom*" is not a really clear statement. Did you eventually mean "*move the lines with `#N/A` to the bottom*"?

Comment: Sub GroupRows()
    Dim rownum As Long
    For rownum = 1 To 1000
    If Cells(rownum, 3).Value = "#N/A" Then
        Rows(rownum).Delete
    Next rownum
    Cells(rownum, 3).Activate
End Sub                                                                                                                             at first I wanted to delete all the rows that have the "#N/A" value, so i used the code above, but it always gives me an error, so I wanted to group them at the bottom first then record a macro to delete them.

Comment: I hope what i am saying is clear.

Comment: Please don't post code in comments (it's unreadable because it is not formatted). Instead [edit] your question to add it. Then describe what your code actually does (what the result is) and what you expect it to do (what the result should be). If there are any errors tell us what the error says and at which line in the code it occurs.

Comment: If you delete rows you need to start the loop from the bottom `For rownum = 1000 To 1 Step -1` because otherwise the rownumbers change while the loop runs.

Comment: Thank you, i've edited the question, let me try the changes you've suggested.

Comment: Yes, the error message is a bit misleading if you are not familiar with VBA. There is a `End If` missing right before `Next rownum`. I reformatted (indented) your code so you can see where it is missing. Nevertheless the loop needs to start from the bottom. *Side Note: Read [VBA Best Practices](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/excel-vba/1107/vba-best-practices) if you are a beginner with VBA this helps a lot to avoid any issues and shows you a good practice how to write code.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how your code would look like if you use the last used row instead of a fixed max row number.

```
Sub GroupRows()
    Dim iRow As Long, lastRow As Long

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Worksheets("MySheetName") 'qualify your sheet

    lastRow = ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 'find last used row

    For iRow = lastRow To 1 Step -1 'run from last used row backwards to row 1
        If ws.Cells(iRow, 3).Text = "#N/A" Or _
           ws.Cells(iRow, 4).Text = "#N/A" Then
            ws.Rows(iRow).Delete
        End If
    Next iRow

    ws.Cells(iRow, 3).Activate
End Sub
```

Your code was missing a `End if` and you should always qualify a `Cells` or `Range` with a worksheet like `ws.Cells` or `ws.Range`.